# Возможно ли получить элемент выходного файла?

Tags: xml, xpath, xslt

В результате преобразований в выходном файле создаётся элемент (назовём его `element1`), значение которого влияет на обработку других элементов.

1. Можно каждый раз делать преобразования для `element1` и проверять значение.
2. Можно это значение внести в переменную.
3. А можно ли это значение брать из `element1`?

Как видно, в данном случае можно прекрасно без этого обойтись, но интересует возможность такого, возможно, пригодится в будущем.

P.S. xslt 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, вы не можете делать запросы против результата прямо на ходу. И вот почему:

- большинство XSLT-процессоров трактуют вывод преобразования как plain-text за некоторыми частными и очень локальными исключениями;
- запись результата идёт потоком , DOM-дерево или какая бы то ни было структура данных для него отсутствует, иначе бы расход памяти был бы пропорционален рамеру выходного файла, это было бы очень расточительно;
- как следствие предыдущих двух пунктов, ясно, что XSLT-процессор не сможет эффективно делать XPath-запросы в таких условиях